# What is the rule with number of levels?

Tags: level-design, levels

I have been making my first game, I have a number of levels I was thinking of making, around 20-30 but I'm not sure if this is too many. Is there a hard and fast rule for number of levels to include in a game?

Comment: As I'm sure you've found from your own research, games have wildly varying numbers of levels - from a handful to hundreds. So there's no simple rule to spit out the right number for any game. Instead, think about your goals: how much play time do you want to offer players? How much play time does each level give you? How much variety do you have in your content and mechanics to make each level interesting? etc...

Comment: I wouldn't think there is a hard and fast rule. Maybe think about what your levels are trying to get the player to do. If you're just adding variety then I would keep the number low, but maybe create groups of levels e.g. level 1 has 5 stages and teaches the player all of the basic skills they'll need, level 2 has five stages that introduce a new mechanic/enemy/graphical theme etc. I think the aim of that style would be keep stepping up the skill required for each level, while adding something new/tweaking something every few levels to keep the player learning.